# "For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames" on every page

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

Whenever I open any Stack Exchange site I come across this message:

> For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames

This problem occurs not only on my laptop, but on my Windows Phone and office MacBook.

This is a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

What should I do? How can I fix this?

Comment: Re: the [bug] tag - [Which browsers are officially supported?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), though you may well be using supported browsers on your other devices.

Comment: chrome at home laptop, IE 11 in windows phone 8.1 and safari in office .

Comment: and you're literally typing stackoverflow.com into all those browsers?

Comment: I just check. I first thought it might be problem with my home system

Comment: Do you mean "not *only* with this laptop"?

Comment: The "duplicate" seems to be specific to uploading an image to imgur, it doesn't occur when just opening the site.

Comment: This is on any site or just stackoverflow.com?

Comment: What happens if you click `OK`? It should unframe the site (and show an other URL in the location bar then)

Comment: It might be worth looking at other sites you visit.  One possible explanation for what you're seeing could be something tampering with all your web traffic in a heavy handed way.

Comment: Try disabling all your extensions; that could help differentiate between external tampering and malware.

Comment: StackExchange does use iframes for ads. If there is some special security reason for your computer not wanting them around, you are going to encounter that on almost every page.

Comment: Also try disabling any profile syncing you have enabled that could be propagating the issue. Perhaps give it a try from an incognito/private browser.

Comment: @TravisJ: It’s the message Stack Overflow creates when it’s framed, not the other way around.

Comment: @minitech - Ah. In that case this is done on purpose correct? I mean, getting around it would require some sort of hack..

Comment: @TravisJ: Yes, but vaibhav is visiting Stack Overflow directly. Frames shouldn’t be involved.

Comment: Is this all happening on the same network?

Comment: You could try https://stackoverflow.com, and inspect the certificate for signs of tampering.  The certificate I see was issued by "DigiCert High Assurance CA-3".

Comment: Dan's thinking about traffic manipulation is plausible and would explain the effect. It could be malicious, or just an ISP doing very strange (sketchy) things. Try fetching over HTTPS, as in https://stackoverflow.com, as well as getting someone else who has little in common with your setup to fetch it as well and send you the HTML ("Save As"). Diff the results of fetching via non-HTTPs, HTTPS, and the page from the other person and see if there's a frame tag present in one but not the others. If there is, your next question is "why?".

Comment: StackExchange sends a header (X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN) that prevents framing in those browsers that honour such flag. Older browsers will ignore it. Is the browser itself who prevents the framing. I don't know much about chromium, but you should check its configuration and your computer for malware, update your browser and check your network. You should not get this message in a properly configured system. Do you have a proxy?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest running a virus scanner. Theres a sort of an exploit where you can get third party sites and bury most of it hidden in an iframe and then use various tricks to either extract data or force unwanted behaviors. This seems to be telling you something is intervening and wrapping stack overflow in a frame, possibly for malevolent reasons. 

Although, the fact your in Ubuntu is a bit strange, as its not particularly heavily targeted by malware, meaning the interference could be upstream.

Comment: Couldn't a virus/malware be ruled out, its not common for a virus/malware to be able to target linux, windows phone, and mac oses at the same time, or I haven't heard or seen one at least. I guess there could be a virus on the router, but that seems just as rare. I think it might be your ISP. Couple posts from superuser [here](http://superuser.com/questions/668620/how-do-i-block-my-isp-from-framing-websites) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/542680/how-to-prevent-my-isp-from-putting-every-website-in-a-frame)

Comment: @PatrickEvans: It could be an extension – even one that isn’t synchronized. I’m not familiar with what’s available on Windows Phone, though.

Comment: I ran into this a month ago. However my question was deleted http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258735/odd-website-behavior-on-stack-overflow-from-ios-8

Comment: I had the same problem with a Chinese ISP as they were randomly wrapping some pages in iframes. Most likely you are having a similar problem. You might want to inspect the HTML in other pages to see if it's happening.

Comment: I have also had this, but on Mac when a page is open in Safari in a private window, and then the computer is rebooted. When Safari comes back, thinking there was a crash and loads back the page, I get this warning.

Comment: To be clear, this happens in both private window, and normal windows.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This message is the result of code we've specifically written to check for other sites opening Stack Exchange Network sites in an iframe. The logic used is JavaScript and is effectively:

```
if (!(parent && parent.WebPlayer) && top != self) {
    top.location.replace(document.location);
    alert('For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.');
}
```

It's a bit more complex/robust than that, but that's the basis of the code.

Logically, based on the fact that this code exists on our site and has for a long time, combined with the fact that you're in the minority of those reporting this issue, I must conclude that your computer is running some kind of malware or software that is trying to iframe our websites. Now, you've said it happens on not one but 3 different devices (and browsers) which is a bit odd and likely rules out malware, so I would have to assume that your internet connection or ISP is injecting an iframe somehow (or maybe your router).

**Things to try:**

- Bypassing any router you might have and connecting to your internet modem directly
- Visit a friend's house with your phone and access their wifi after confirming they can view Stack sites without issue
- Using a public internet connection (like a coffee shop wifi) to see if the issue remains
- Try incognito mode on some of your browsers
- If all else fails, perhaps try switching to a different ISP (extreme option)

The bottom line is *something* is injecting an iframe to web pages that your devices visit... This *something* has to be in common with all 3 of your devices so I can fairly safely assume that the router or modem or ISP is to blame. Unfortunately, if this is the case, there isn't a ton we can do to help you beyond the above suggestions. Sorry. :(

Comment: Though he says this happens both at home and in the office, making it even more likely - though I agree it's gotta be one of the many things you mention.

Comment: @OGHaza, Maybe (s)he VPN's through their home connection for privacy or firewall bypassing??

Comment: Actually rereading the OP there's mention of an "Office Macbook" not necessarily being accessed from work just by work hardware.

Comment: @indivisible, I was referring to "chrome at home  ... safari in office" in their first comment. But yup you're right, that's possible.

Comment: Well, this answers part of [my deleted question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258735/odd-website-behavior-on-stack-overflow-from-ios-8)

Comment: @OGHaza, I actually think that could be a mistranslation and/or incorrect preposition usage. The piece "*chrome **at** home laptop*" I feel was intended as "*Chrome **on** home laptop*" and thus think the same is then likely true for the second clause about the work situation which I then read as "*safari **on** office [laptop]*". Not a huge deal though, just how I interpreted the text.

Comment: @Ind, yeah you're probably right - otherwise the situation seems more or less impossible

Comment: What is this `parent.WebPlayer` thing?

Comment: A relic from when we once used MouseStats to "play" recorded user sessions on our site.

Comment: @Haney didn't mention you should use an HTTP proxy tool like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to actually figure out what's going on. Anything else is simply guess and check, and may not help you solve the actual problem.

Comment: @Haney I'm seeing this for the first time ever today while at the same time seeing 'Powered by AMP HTML' messages in the console. Not sure if you ever work at SO anymore but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I've started noticing this recently on Safari 11, usually when restoring a tab. The pop up appears 3 times, and then the ads load.

Comment: I get this message whenever I start Chrome 60.0.3112.90 on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)  with [this page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/164018/what-are-some-ways-to-keep-the-player-engaged-in-an-endless-game) open from the previous session. I think it does have to do with ads, as the message occasionally pops up several times, and ads load once I dismiss it.

Comment: @Haney As a developer I somehow both like and hate your conclusion: `Logically, based on the fact that this code exists on our site and has for a long time…` On the one hand it makes sense to assume the code is working 100% of time correctly, on the other hand there's no code immune to bugs (bugs of web-browsers as well). But I just observed that weird behaviour on my laptop and I guess I have steps for you to reproduce it. 1) Open the following page: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261697/remove-escape-on-touchbar-in-safari 2) Close the tab 3) Restore it with Cmd+Shift-T 4) Voilà!

Comment: @Haney my environment: macOS 10.14 + Safari 12.0 or macOS 10.13 + Safari 11.1.2. It's not reproduced neither in Chrome nor in Firefox. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Idolon no repro here. Gotta be browser software on PC, or ISP injection, or something else.

Comment: @Haney IMHO ISP is out of question here – first of all because of HTTPS, and second, because I can reproduce it with different ISPs. Buuut… I was incomplete in my description. I can reproduce it when I open the mentioned question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261697/remove-escape-on-touchbar-in-safari , then after it loads I **need to scroll it** a bit down and then close with Cmd+W and restore with Cmd+Shift+T. It doesn't reproduce if I don't scroll. I can record a video if you're interested to nail it down.

Comment: @Idolon I can also reproduce it this way

Comment: @Haney Were you able to reproduce it with the updated steps? Should I record a video (could be clean install in VM as well)? Or you're not interested, and I should just leave it and forget? :)

Comment: @Idolon Probably comments on a four-year-old question are not the best way to get support. Use a new question, or use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Idolon I can reproduce this in Safari on macOS Mojave also.

Comment: I get this frequently on Ipad when I switch back to Safari after using other applications for a while and a stack exchange page was already loaded.

Comment: I recently switched from Chrome to Safari, and I never saw this behavior on Chrome. I now see this whenever restoring a tab or returning (via back button) to a StackExchange site. I thought it had to do with the way I navigated to the site originally (i.e. from a link on Google or Github), but now I am not sure, since I get it if I navigate by entering https://stackoverflow.com in the location bar, open any external link from any SO question, and then go back to the question using the browser back button.

Comment: There must be an incompatibility with the code on site and Safari. I guess there is an edge case what the code should handle since it is super annoying for the users.

Answer (score 4):

StackExchange pages do not allow framing and contain JS code to detect that the page is inside a frame. This is meant to prevent [some kinds of attacks](http://seclab.skku.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/KoreanClickjacking_CR.pdf).

It is possible that your computer has malware or browser extension on it which rewrites the DOM in your browser, inserting the content into a frame, which triggers this behaviour.

It is also possible that your ISP is doing the same.

Comment: I didn't understand what "framing" meant here until I did a bit of googling. For the benefit of others in the same boat, I've added a link in your text to show that at least *some* of these kinds of attack are more commonly known as ***clickjacking***.

Comment: _framing_ means to put something in a frame. Like a picture in a picture frame, or an HTML document in an iframe. The attacks that are prevented are not called framing.

Comment: I take it for granted you know more about such matters than me. All I know is what I picked up from 20 seconds googling **browser framing attack** (which gave me the impression it's more of an issue for smartphones than PC-based Internet access). Since I don't have a smartphone (on account of not being smart enough to use one! :) that was about all I felt I *needed* to know at the moment.

Comment: I insist that this is caused to malware or browser extension as it happen whenever my virus software is being disabled.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Chrome on Linux the problem might be caused by [Smooth Gestures](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smooth-gestures-plus/kdcjmllhmhnnadianfhhnoefgcdbpdap) extension.

Comment: And trackpad gestures on Mac too.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this issue with Chrome on Linux, and the way I've found to reproduce it is to enter any page on a SE site (here the issue does *not* happen yet), then hit the back button on the browser, then hit the forward button (thus, going back to the page), and here the issue *does* happen.

As other users pointed out in comments, I also see the page loads fine, but then before the ads start to load, this popup appears. When I confirm the popup, the ads load.